# Bleachbit error when cleaning firefox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox, bleachbit

After doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 a couple of days ago Bleachbit reports the following errors when cleaning Firefox:

```
Error in execution of <bleachbit.Command.Function instance at 0x7f9f34b60680>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/bleachbit/Worker.py", line 84, in execute
    for ret in cmd.execute(self.really_delete):
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/bleachbit/Command.py", line 146, in execute
    self.func(self.path)
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/bleachbit/Special.py", line 280, in delete_mozilla_url_history
    FileUtilities.execute_sqlite3(path, cmds)
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/bleachbit/FileUtilities.py", line 307, in execute_sqlite3
    '%s: %s' % (Common.decode_str(exc), path))
DatabaseError: UNIQUE constraint failed: moz_places.url: /home/user/.mozilla/firefox/kzebxoz8.default/places.sqlite
```

History is not deleted in Firefox. Everything else appears to be cleaned properly.

Is there a fix for this?

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Update to [BleachBit version 1.12](https://www.bleachbit.org/news/bleachbit-112) which fixes this exact issue

> Fix error UNIQUE constraint failed error cleaning Firefox (reported by danjackson1 and gravy45)

P.S. The version of BleachBit in Ubuntu's repositories is out of date almost all the time because of their policies, so I highly recommend always getting it from the official BleachBit site.